# Change orientation to automatically landscape windows phone phonegap

Tags: xaml, cordova, windows-phone

I'm building my first phone app using PhoneGap for windows phone, I'm trying to make it so that it automatically changes to landscape orientation when loaded I have changed this in the MainPage.xaml

```
SupportedOrientations="LandscapeOrPortrait" Orientation="Portrait"
```

to this...

```
SupportedOrientations="Landscape" Orientation="Landscape"
```

and when I load it on my phone it still allows me to swap to portrait, am I missing something? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem now, in the App.xaml file there was a section that said;

```
PhoneApplicationPage.Orientation="Landscape"
```

Not entirely sure why this was even there, but it needed to be removed!